# Angular Email Validation Component/Service

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 app that I would like to leverage an existing email validation service used elsewhere in my system. It's a REST API, I simply send the email to it and it returns an object with a few values, one of which is a boolean `valid`. I also want to make this re-usable and as usable multiple time in the same form, for example two email fields within the same form.

To start out, I've made a service that has a `validateEmail` method which does the actual `GET` call, and maps the response `json` to a `UserEmailVerification` object.

I then made an `EmailComponent` that `imports` the service and has a debounced method to call it.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserEmailVerification} from "../../model/email/email-verification.model";
import {ValidateEmailService} from "../../services/validate-email.service";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email',
  templateUrl: 'email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['email.component.scss']
})
export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public email: string = "";
  public label: string = "";
  public error: string = "";
  public validate: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private _validateEmailService: ValidateEmailService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.validate
      .pipe(debounceTime(600))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._validateEmailService.validateEmail(this.email).subscribe( (userEmailVerification: UserEmailVerification) => {
          if (userEmailVerification.valid === true) {
            this.error = "";
          } else {
            this.error = "This is not a valid email address.";
          }
        });
        }
      );
  }

  public input(e) {
    this.validate.next();
  }
}
```

I've then imported the `EmailComponent` to the component that handles the form, and included the `EmailComponent`'s selector element in the form view. The `EmailComponent`'s view looks like this:

```
<label>
  {{ this.label }}
  <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="bob.smith@someemail.com" [(ngModel)]="email"
     (input)="this.input($event)">
  <p class="error" *ngIf="this.error">{{ this.error }}</p>
</label>
```

This works, and as you type an email in, the debounce works and gives a validation error as intended. However, it's not hooked up to the parent component/form so the validation doesn't matter and filling it out in the form doesn't update the parent component.

My question is then twofold, is this the best angular way to implement a custom email validator so it can be used in multiple locations? If not, what is? If it is, how do I connect the two components so that the validated email component/field maps to an attribute of the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Just created a file in angular6 project validator/email.ts on root
email.ts:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class EmailValidator {

    static isValid(control: FormControl) {
        const re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/.test(control.value);

        if (re) {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            "invalidEmail": true
        };

    }
}
```

and then in my component where i wanted to validate it in component.ts file,

```
import { EmailValidator } from '../validator/email';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  createForm: FormGroup;
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.validateForm()
  }
 validateForm() {
    this.createForm= this.formBuilder.group({

      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValid])],

    })
  }
}
```

now in component.html where you have email input to valdate:

```
    <form [formGroup]="AgentForm" novalidate>
<div>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="this.email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
//error message you want to show
<div *ngIf="!createForm.controls.email.valid  &&
        createForm.controls.email.dirty">
          <span>Invalid email address.</span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to experiment with this, as I need the email validation to be done via a `GET` in a service to an API rather than just self contained.

Comment: making an http request through a service will be the bad idea as it takes an extra http which not a recommended method

Comment: Then how would you suggest I make an HTTP request?

Comment: dude you don't need to make http call for this, if you interested then i will update my answer step by step to make you understand it easily

Comment: You don't seem to understand my question. There is a specific service I have as an API that checks if the email is valid, in use, etc. I want to leverage that as a validator in Angular.